# "Infinitivkonstruktion mit zu" (Infinitiv + zu) durch einen dass-Satz ersetzen

Tags: grammaticality

Kann man aus *jeder* "Infinitivkonstruktion mit zu" (Infinitiv + zu) einen dass-Satz machen?

In [EasyDeutsch](https://easy-deutsch.de/satzbau/infinitiv-mit-zu/) steht:

> haben/sein + Adjektiv + Infinitiv mit zu ("dass-Satz" so gut wie nie möglich). Bei finden + Adjektiv ist der "dass-Satz" aber meistens möglich.
>
> Ich habe Lust, mit dir ins Kino zu gehen.
> Es ist einfach, einen Job in Deutschland zu finden.
>
> Ich finde es super, dir beim Deutsch lernen helfen zu können.
> Ich finde es super, dass ich dir beim Deutsch lernen helfen kann.

In den anderen Quellen z.B. [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/Infinitiv.html?MenuId=Sentence6324#Anchor-Infinitivkonstruktion-49575) wird das gar nicht erwähnt.

Beispiel:

> Ist es möglich, die Rechnung per Post zu erhalten?
> Ist es möglich, dass ich die Rechnung per Post erhalte?
>
> Er hat Angst (davor), angegriffen zu werden.
> Er hat Angst (davor), dass er angegriffen wird.

Nach der Erklärung von EasyDeutsch sind die dass-Sätze in den Beispielen nicht erlaubt aber ich habe sie oft gehört bzw. gelesen.

Gibt es eine feste Regel, wann man Infinitivkonstruktionen durch einen dass-Satz ersetzen kann?

Answer (score 2):

**Nein.**

> Er versteht, dass er isst.
>
> Er versteht zu essen.

Hier gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung. Man kann also nicht jede Infinitivkonstruktion in einen *dass*-Satz umwandeln.

Comment: @Arsak Meine Antwort beantwortet immer noch die erste Frage in der Frage (die jetzt zwei Fragen enthält.) Ich lass OP mal Zeit sich zu entscheiden...

Comment: Der Unterschied in der Bedeutung wird hier aber durch die zwei unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen von "verstehen" verursacht. Das ist eine wirklich skurrile Ausnahme.

Comment: @HJay Aber wenn "dass"-Sätze und Infinitivkonstruktion frei austauschbar wären, könnte die Bedeutung von "verstehen" nicht davon abhängen, welche von beiden man verwendet. Und die Frage ist eine sehr allgemeine: "Kann man aus _jeder_ (!) "Infinitivkonstruktion mit zu" (Infinitiv + zu) einen dass-Satz machen?" Nicht aus jeder, mehr wollte ich hier gar nicht zeigen.

Comment: Die Beispiel sind durchaus schlechtes Deutsch. Aber das ist doch gerade der Punkt. Man kann eben nicht beliebig *zu* oder *dass* anknüpfen. In stehenden Wendungen haben die Partikel eine gewisse Bedeutung, die man hier versuchen kann zu übertragen. Allerdings wäre "Essen verstehen" so fabelhaft wie "mit Tieren reden". Deshalb würde in der Regel niemand Abwandlungen davon verwenden.

Comment: @vectory Nein, "verstehen zu" + Infinitiv ist gutes Deutsch, und lässt sich problemlos verallgemeinern: "Er versteht zu leben", "Er versteht zu sterben", ...

Comment: Erstens ist die Semantik zweifelhaft, da weder Essen noch Sterben Verständnis vorraussetzen. Zweitens würde ich tatsächlich entweder "Er versteht es, zu ..." sagen (vielleicht versehentlich "Er versteht's zu ..." gehört) oder "Er versteht X" (X=Englisch, Computer, Frauen, das Leben etc.), oder aber "Er kann `ÌNF`". Man kann *zu etwas stehen*, etwas kann *einem zustehen*, etwas kann *einem stehen*, und man kann *etwas verstehen*. Aber "etwas" kann nicht immer mit *zu-infinitiv* belegt werden. *Schlecht* ist vielleicht das falsche Wort, aber unünlich ist das Bsp. allemal.

Comment: Die Verneinung funktioniert auch nicht, "Er versteht nicht zu essen" wäre doppeldeutig ("es nicht zu" bzw. "nicht es zu" löst dies, das ist die Crux; der gehobene Stand könnte sarkastisch "zu hungern" sagen), aber "Er versteht zu essen nicht" klingt gebrochen (oder etwa nicht?). "Er versteht zu leben" könnte dem Inhalt nach ein gehobener Register sein, so hört es sich für mich jedenfalls an, in dem Kenntnis von Tischmanieren oder guter Ernährung - was auch immer du ausdrücken wolltest - eigentlich vorrausgesetzt wird. jedenfalls wenn die Behauptung nicht durch ein Adjektiv eingeschränkt wird.

Answer (score 1):

> Kann man aus jeder "Infinitivkonstruktion mit zu" (Infinitiv + zu)
>   einen dass-Satz machen?

Nein, das geht nicht. Canoo liefert dazu doch ausführliche Erklärungen. Besonders wichtig ist die Tatsache, dass dies nur dann funktioniert, wenn das Subjekt des Infinitiv identisch ist mit dem Subjekt oder Objekt des regierenden Hauptsatzes.

Außerdem hängst es stark vom Prädikat ab. Verben der Wahrnehmung oder Äußerung wie sehen, befürchten, vermuten können dass-Sätze bilden.

Siehe hier: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/dass-Satz.html)