# What is the grammar in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar-identification, infinitive, subordinate-clause

This is a sentence for Donna Leon's Acqua Alta, chapter 18:

> Stattdessen fragte er: »Besteht die Chance, sie heute noch **zu bekommen**?«

Now, I would expect this sentence would be written more like this:

> Stattdessen fragte er: "Besteht die Chance, dass Sie sie heute bekommen können?"

I do not recognize the grammar that permits the first version. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phrase like

> …, sie heute noch zu bekommen

can be referred to as **uneingeleiteter Infinitivsatz** (*infinitive clause without subjunction*). In

> … die Chance, sie heute noch zu bekommen

it is used **attributiv** (*attributively*, like a relative clause is). *Uneingeleitete Infinitivsätze*, however, can also be *Inhaltssätze*, i.e. serve as the subject or object of another sentence:

> - Sie heute noch zu bekommen ist unmöglich *(Subjektsatz)*
> - Ich glaube, sie heute noch zu bekommen *(Objektsatz)*

All *Infinitivsätze* have in common that they have no subject and obiously no finite verb.

Oftentimes, *Infinitivsätze* can be transferred into *dass*-clauses and vice versa. However, in both directions it's **not always possible**. This, e.g., was asked [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50834/infinitivkonstruktion-mit-zu-infinitiv-zu-durch-einen-dass-satz-ersetzen).